# How to keep my dropdowns below my nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple top-of-page nav bar for a website, with dropdowns. It's essentially working, save that I don't know how to make the dropdowns all appear at the same height, and below my nav bar.
Here's an example of what's wrong.
https://gyazo.com/e27972ed98be6ca3faa7d5be980b6658
The navbar stretches to accommodate the tallest button, but each dropdown's height is determined by its corresponding button's height rather than the navbar's. I've tried to get them to all fill the same height but haven't been able to figure out how. Here's my code:

```css
:root {
  --accent_1: #8B8BAE;
  --light: #F0F3F5;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: var(--button-text);
}

a {
  color: var(--light);
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--accent_1);
}

nav p {
  color: var(--light);
}

.header_element {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: var(--accent_1);
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header_element:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/">
        <p class="header_button">Siberian Cats</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element moc_header">
      <p class="header_button moc_button">Meet Our Cats</p>
      <ul class="dropdown moc_dropdown">
        <div>
          <li><a href="/available-kittens">Available Kittens</a></li>
          <li><a href="/expecting-litters">Expecting Litters</a></li>
          <li><a href="/our-breeders">Our Breeders</a></li>
          <li><a href="/sold-kittens">Sold Kittens</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="header_element ai_header">
      <p class="header_button ai_button">Adoption Information</p>
      <ul class="dropdown ai_dropdown">
        <div>
          <li><a href="/bringing-kitten-home">Bringing Your Kitten Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/breeder-info">Breeder Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="/conditions-for-sale">Conditions for Sale</a></li>
          <li><a href="/health-contract">Health Contract</a></li>
          <li><a href="/pricing-discounts">Pricing Discounts</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="header_element cys_header">
      <p class="header_button cys_button">Caring for Your Siberian</p>
      <ul class="dropdown cys_dropdown">
        <div>
          <li><a href="/general-care">General Care</a></li>
          <li><a href="/diet">Diet</a></li>
          <li><a href="/second-cats">Introducing a Second Cat</a></li>
          <li><a href="/resources">Resources</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/responsible-breeding">
        <p class="header_button">Responsible Breeding</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/testimonials">
        <p class="header_button">Testimonials</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/application">
        <p class="header_button">Application</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/contact">
        <p class="header_button">Contact</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/about">
        <p class="header_button">About</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </div>

</body>
```

Thanks for any insight! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must add "position: relative" to your .header_element class and "top: 105%" to your .dropdown class like this:

```css
:root {
  --accent_1: #8B8BAE;
  --light: #F0F3F5;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: var(--button-text);
}

a {
  color: var(--light);
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--accent_1);
}

nav p {
  color: var(--light);
}

.header_element {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: var(--accent_1);
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 105%;
}

.header_element:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/">
        <p class="header_button">Siberian Cats</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element moc_header">
      <p class="header_button moc_button">Meet Our Cats</p>
      <ul class="dropdown moc_dropdown">
        <div>
          <li><a href="/available-kittens">Available Kittens</a></li>
          <li><a href="/expecting-litters">Expecting Litters</a></li>
          <li><a href="/our-breeders">Our Breeders</a></li>
          <li><a href="/sold-kittens">Sold Kittens</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="header_element ai_header">
      <p class="header_button ai_button">Adoption Information</p>
      <ul class="dropdown ai_dropdown">
        <div>
          <li><a href="/bringing-kitten-home">Bringing Your Kitten Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/breeder-info">Breeder Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="/conditions-for-sale">Conditions for Sale</a></li>
          <li><a href="/health-contract">Health Contract</a></li>
          <li><a href="/pricing-discounts">Pricing Discounts</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="header_element cys_header">
      <p class="header_button cys_button">Caring for Your Siberian</p>
      <ul class="dropdown cys_dropdown">
        <div>
          <li><a href="/general-care">General Care</a></li>
          <li><a href="/diet">Diet</a></li>
          <li><a href="/second-cats">Introducing a Second Cat</a></li>
          <li><a href="/resources">Resources</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/responsible-breeding">
        <p class="header_button">Responsible Breeding</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/testimonials">
        <p class="header_button">Testimonials</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/application">
        <p class="header_button">Application</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/contact">
        <p class="header_button">Contact</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header_element">
      <a href="/about">
        <p class="header_button">About</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057402/how-to-keep-my-dropdowns-below-my-nav-bar#

  <div class="content">
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </div>

</body>
```